# Customer registration

Tags: magento-1.9

When I register a customer in the admin I get this warning. There does not seem to be any problem but I don't understand why we get this warning because the first name and last name have been entered. CE v1.9.1.0

[image: Warning]

Comment: have you alter any core code or added observer related to customer?

Comment: Does the first name or last name update? I would suggest on a dev environment disable all third party modules and see does it save. If it does then the issue is with one of the third party modules.

Comment: Yes. Both names update which is why I couldn't understand why the warning is being displayed. We are using Web-forms extension so I have contacted Mageme.com to see if this is related to their extension.